# OpenGL - One Step Further On The Way To Faster QUADS Rendering

Tags: performance, opengl, stream, vbo

I have been experimenting a bit and can render around 3 millions of GL_QUADS onto screen now using

```
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, nVertexCount);
```

I also use multiple buffering, cycling through 18 vertex buffer objects of 1 million vertices each. Every vertex position is computed using compressed data stored on the heap and a simple computation. I use

```
ptr = (float*)glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
```

and

```
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```

to write every single vertex to the buffer objects each frame. When a buffer object is full, I unmap it, call glDrawArrays, and bind and map the next VBO to stream further vertex data. When all 18 have been used, I logically bind the first one and start over.

From my experience, using the mapping of VBOs is almost twice as fast as using heap arrays for vertex data. How do I know? Because, since I render 3 millions of GL_QUADS, the frame rate is significantly lower than 30 fps. I simply can observe with my eyes how the frame rate is twice for VBOs.

I also made the observation, that calling glDrawArrays twice in succession on each filled vertex buffer object (resulting in twice as many quads to be rendered, but once the effort to stream the vertex data) - to be only insignificantly slower than rendering only once. Therefore, I assume the major bottleneck to be the streaming of vertex data into vertex buffer objects (a 2 GHz dualcore is 60% busy with it!!).

Right now each vertex takes 3 floats plus 2 floats for texture coord. (20 bytes in total). I guess I could shorten that amount to 3 GL_SHORT plus 2 GL_SHORT for texture coord. using translation matrices (5 bytes in total), but that would speed up only by 4 times. (And somehow sizeof(GL_SHORT) gives 4 on my system, so I'm not sure about that either.)

At any rate, there are games out there, which even are pretty old already but render far more than 3 millions of primitives onto the screen each frame afaik (and they inevitably have to stream these vertices, because no GPU could hold so much data) and still get decent framerates of over 100 fps!

I am sure, I'm still missing some important point in the process, but I just can't figure out what it is. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
These are loose quads like in a particle system. (Or rather because each might end up having a different texture on it (Textures are taken from subtextures of a single one, so no extensive binding ;) ))

Comment: Are these loose quads (each quad having vertices that are independent of other quads, such as in a particle system) or is this a mesh made up of quads?

Comment: By the way: *"...are pretty old already but render far more than 3 millions..."*. I would really doubt that. The fact that the world consists of more than 3 million triangles doesn't mean they're all rendered every frame. Think of view frustum culling, portal culling, PVS, ..., to name a few of the techniques these games surely apply. But this doesn't mean it helps in your case, just to clarify that you cannot just make such simple comparisons between scene complexity and performance.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas:
Loose quads. See my edit.

at Christian Rau:
I have a frustum culling - but using it drains more CPU than simply writing 20 bytes. In my case I am trying to draw even more than 3 millions of quads. If 15 out of 40 millions efficiently get culled out later, its great, but I would still need to render more than 3 millions...

Comment: @Fejwin Nowadays, in times of excessive batching and instanced rendering, such CPU-bound techniques like frustum culling and the like don't always give the intended performance-boost (like in your case it seems). That's why you cannot make such simple comparisons to other applications, that were built having completely different optimization goals in mind, let aside that the assumption they render more than 3 million triangles per frame was probably wrong, anyway.

Comment: @ChristianRau They render fewer primitives than 3 millions? To be honest, I do not know exactly how much the average is. Perhaps you can give me a hint? Basically I understand that my approach is not optimized. Any suggestions what I could do?

Comment: Try to multiply three matrices for each quad for getting rendering. When it has finished, call me to say how it was...

Comment: btw. sizeof(GL_SHORT) is 4 because GL_SHORT maps to an int. What you are (were) looking for is most likely sizeof(GLshort)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am sure, I'm still missing some important point in the process

The point should be *Do I need to draw 3 MB of triangles?*, instead of *How can I break the hardware  limit?*

The limit you shall acknoledge should be *hardware*. Transfer rates, GPU clock and memory clock are characteristic that cannot be overriden without newer hardware. Indeed you should try to make an efficient use of the current hardware.

As I can understand, you need to update vertex buffers while rendering; so you map the buffer object, updates the data, unmap and render. I suppose you do it repeatly. In this case you have to consider the transfer rate from CPU to GPU; can you reduce the data required for rendering the scene? Maybe interpolating key vertex positions?

For instance, if I need to render a terrain, I can send billions of triangles to render a perfect terrain. But surely I can reach the same result by using only the most important one. Using less triangles without distorting the good result, make me able to do more and more.

At 1920x1080 there are 2 MB of pixels... I need to use 2 MB of triangles for drawing it? Maybe a fragment shader would perform better.

There are many techiques used for reducing processing loads (both on CPU and GPU) and transfer rates:

- culling
- level of detail
- instanced rendering
- key-frame animation
- skeletal animation

Comment: Just now I realized that you are completely right! I put all my vertices into a VBO and rendered them without updating - the result was still very laggy. Therefore, it is a hardware limit! =) I will focus on going from quads to triangles now, since these aren't deprecated and hopefully will boost performance a little. From now on I will store all my vertices in a VBO for good without excessive updating, since the GPU can't render all its memory lag free anyway. I learned that today! Thank you very much! =)

Answer (score 1):

There are actually quite a few things you can do (or which are done to get more throughput).
I am just skimming a few, as this can (and does) fill a (or more) book(s), though.

1. Draw triangles, not quads. Ultimately, the quads will be splitted to tris anyway (graphics hardware is optimized for triangle processing).
2. When you have big objects consisting of so many triangles, you  are going to use strips and fans wherever you can (reduces the amount of vertex data to be sent from 3N to N+2).
3. Clever caching of the data (especially when rendering large scenes) is vital. As you have observed, data transfer is the bottleneck in the system. So basically every engine is heavily optimized to avoid unnecessary data transfers. This is application dependent though. There this is also a topic where many books can be written about (and have been).

I can recommend these books as an entry to the topic:

http://www.realtimerendering.com/

http://www.gameenginebook.com/

Comment: "Draw triangles, not quads" why? that'd just be extremely inefficient wouldn't it? a quad shares its last 2 verts. the same way that triangle strip does. just using a single vert for the next tri. i don't think they'd be so dumb to dupe the last two verts for each triangle, wasting tons of gpu memory as if somehow the indexing will be faster. i know for a fact more memory makes it way slower. example, single int color, vs 3 float rgb's. if opengl were to do any automatic optimization to the vertex data given, they'd surely have converted the floats to bytes. they don't.

Comment: and the reason why is because you define how the vbo memory you upload is to be used.

Comment: also the whole reason for [vbo indexing](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-9-vbo-indexing/) is to save vertex memory when using triangles. quads seemed to simply implement it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

> Every vertex position is computed using compressed data stored on the heap and a simple computation.

Maybe vertex or geometry shader can do it instead?

> At any rate, there are games out there, which even are pretty old already but render far more than 3 millions of primitives onto the screen each frame afaik (and they inevitably have to stream these vertices, because no GPU could hold so much data)

`3000000 * 20 bytes = 60 megabytes` that easily within reach of even older GPUs.

Comment: These are just simple add and store operations, perhaps 30 bytes worth for up to 240 bytes of vertex data. My example with 3 million vertices is surely rather small. If you take 30 millions, no graphics card would be able to deal with it 3 years ago.

Comment: @Fejwin: You forget, that much of what you see on screen is reused data. You can, for example have only a small number of human character models, but by change of textures and adjustment of a few skinning matrices give them a very distinct look. Also 3 years ago graphics cards with >512MB of memory were quite common. For example I'm still working and developing on a GeForce8800GTX with 768MB RAM, which I bought November 2006, i.e. almost 5 years ago. Before that I had a GeForce7800 with 256MB of RAM, and before that a Radeon9800 with also 256MB, too, bought 2003.

Comment: @datenwolf: It seems I am trying to develop on a graphics card from 2008 which lags behind your 2006 one! =) (Shouldn't expect much from a laptop on board GPU). I think you guys are right! I could store all needed data on the GPU. Because, even then the GPU couldn't render all of it in one go at good performance, so it is a hardware limit.